# TCP sequence number collisions across sessions

Tags: tcp

What prevents sequence number collisions across multiple TCP sessions from the same (source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port) tuple? In more detail, I'm wondering what prevents scenarios like the following:

1. TCP session S1 created.
2. Some packets get sent on S1, including one with TCP sequence number N.
3. TCP session S1 closed.
4. TCP session S2 created with the same (src IP, src port, dst IP, dst port) as S1.
5. Packet from step (2), with TCP sequence number N, is still in flight and finally arrives at the recipient while N is in the receive window for session S2.

If this happens, the packet with sequence number N from the old session (S1) would get passed to the application in place of the packet with sequence number N from the new session.

I think this scenario is the same as TCP session hijacking. But I'm wondering what prevents this from happening accidentally, just because two consecutive sessions for the same endpoints happen to pick the same sequence numbers.

Comment: The initial sequence number is randomized for exactly this reason, rather than being zero or 1.

Comment: Does that mean that the protection is just a probabilistic mechanism? There's still some chance that a packet from the old sessions happens to arrive within the appropriate sequence number window on the new session.

Comment: Remember that packets are dead after 1MSL, and the TIME_WAIT mechanism ensures that connections between the same IP:port pairs can't occur within 2*MSL.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the TIME_WAIT mechanism. I guess this relies on some clock synchronization between endpoints, to enforce that packets are dead after 1MSL. But given appropriate synchronization, it sounds like a robust mechanism. Do you want to write that as an answer?